# Node.js remove tags from svg/xml

Tags: node.js, xml, parsing, svg

currently I'm trying to remove all group tags from a svg file.
Here a little snippet:

```
<g id="Wasser">
        <path d="M191.386,108.491l14.88,0.04l9.507,6.465l4.563,-6.465l-6.465,-22.057l-22.865,10.228l0.38,11.789Z" style="fill:#bbdefb;stroke:#fff;stroke-width:1px;"/>
        <path d="M104.529,0l26.145,51.148l-4.754,20.916l9.507,2.377l53.242,-13.31l75.108,-46.586l0.951,-14.545l-160.199,0Z" style="fill:#bbdefb;stroke:#fff;stroke-width:1px;"/>
    </g>
    <g id="GB">
        <path d="M126.788,145.167l-1.638,-14.184l5.934,-4.084l-0.128,-3.509l-16.185,-8.593l-11.881,11.314l5.806,6.699l-14.932,7.577l33.024,4.78Z" style="fill:#db0a5b;stroke:#fff;stroke-width:1px;"/>
        <path d="M126.788,145.167l6.894,0.998l9.736,-5.993l6.516,-15.152l-7.986,-4.74l-10.864,6.619l-5.934,4.084l1.638,14.184Z" style="fill:#db0a5b;stroke:#fff;stroke-width:1px;"/>
    </g>
```

I would do it by making if conditions and using string replace in JS for `</g>`, but how can I remove the group tags with the ids? My current approach isn't working because the default replace function needs an exact string.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'd strongly recommend using an XML parsing module for node. For example, when using [sax-js](https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js), you only need to implement the `ontext` callback to receive just text data, but not tags etc. events.